# Back button after webview

Tags: android, navigation, onkeydown

I've got 2 activities *Activity A* & *Activity B* (webview)
What i'm trying to do is, when the webview can't go back anymore, it will display Activity A and on press again prompt for exit

Here is Activity A :

```
import com.jeumont.app.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;



public class frontpage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frontpage); 
}
}
```

The webview which contains the backpress function :

```
public class webview extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Init Barre de chargement
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Chargement en cours", true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webapp);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_web_app);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
         //On enleve le progress quand la page est chargée
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
              { 
                pd.dismiss();
                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);
              }
```

So i've tried several things to make this work.

```
public void onBackPressed (){

    if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack(); 

    }
 super.onBackPressed();
```

works as expected, the webview goes back and when it can't anymore switch back to activity A and if you press again leaves the app

i'm actually using :

```
public void onBackPressed (){

    if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();       
    }

    else

    {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Voulez vous quitter ?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

    }
}
```

the prompts works fine, but it pops out when the webview can't go back anymore, if yes pressed you go back to activity A

how can i make this prompt pop when the current activity is A and not the webview?
i don't really know how to do this, i've heard about fragments, is that the way to do it ?

hope this is clear.

Comment: can you please elaborate more not understood what is your actual requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override onBackPressed() in both the activity.

In Activity A:

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed (){
                   //AlertDialog to exit the app.

        }
```

In Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed (){

        if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack(); 

        }else{
              super.onBackPressed(); 
         }

    }
```

Comment: awesome man ! i didn't think of that att all, and yet so simple ! thanks !!

Comment: @MuiMui,super.onBackPressed(); is goes under else case other wise is called even webview back stack available.

Comment: yep, i forgot it in the webview class, anyway override the onbackpress in the other activity was the way to do it !

Answer (score 0):

In your Avtivity A, override `onBackPressed` and put code of showing prompt:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Voulez vous quitter ?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.show();
}
```

And remove the same from webview's activity in else block.

Comment: thank you for your time, it was it, but got the answer like 1min before, will definitely come back to +rep. thanks again